# how do I reinstall Windows live mail on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-live-mail

Cant get into my live mail account since upgrading Windows 10. I have tried downloading Windows essentials but didnt work.

Comment: [Update required to keep using Windows Live Mail 2012 with Microsoft accounts](http://www.windowscentral.com/update-required-keep-using-windows-live-mail-2012-microsoft-accounts)

Comment: @DavidPostill I got that in an email from Microsoft, I am using live mail 2009 and it continues to work without upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Live Mail (2009) Version 14 works fine on my PCs upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7.    I have not attempted a fresh install on Windows 10.

You need the Standalone Installer for Windows Live Essentials (2009) which you can find here:
http://www.geekonthepc.com/2010/10/10/get-the-old-windows-live-essentials-2009-back/
Windows Live Version 14.0.8117.0416 - File Size 138,086 KB

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** As of January 10, 2017, Windows Essentials 2012 and all other versions of Windows essentials is no longer supported on Windows 10, and is unavailable for download.

---

> I am using live mail 2009

Windows Live mail 2009 is not supported in Windows 10 and is currently discontinued. It is supported only for XP.

> I have tried downloading Windows essentials but didn't work.

Windows Live Essentials 2009 and Windows Live Essentials 2011 are discontinued and are no longer available for download.

> how do I reinstall Windows live mail on Windows 10?

Live mail you are using (Live mail 2009) cannot be installed on Windows 10. Live mail 2012 however can be installed on Windows 10 though it is not recommended.

Recent changes in Outlook.com have affected working of Windows Live Essentials 2009 and 2011. Here is what Microsoft [says](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/livemail-wlinstall/important-information-about-your-email-service/dee64671-a2a4-443b-84c3-16f1785fb99f) about Windows Live Essentials 2009 and 2011,

> We don't know what is going to happen with Windows Live Mail 2009 on
>   XP and 2011 on Vista. It is clear that users will no longer be able to
>   sign in with a migrated account to synchronize contacts and calendar,
>   and they won't be able to synchronize mail messages and folders using
>   DeltaSync. Whether the programs will continue to work in other
>   respects (e.g. as a POP3, IMAP and NNTP client) remains to be seen.

It is recommended that you switch to new [Mail and Calendar](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/mail-and-calendar/9wzdncrfhvqm) on Windows 10 as Windows live essentials are not supported on Windows 10. <s>Else try using Windows Live Essentials 2012 as it currently working on Windows 10.</s>

**References:**

1. [Supported Windows versions for essentials](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18614/windows-essentials#wetabs=we2012)
2. [Important information about your email service - answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/livemail-wlinstall/important-information-about-your-email-service/dee64671-a2a4-443b-84c3-16f1785fb99f) (The forth point says how Windows Live Essentials 2009 and 2012 are affected.)